# CSS -webkit-transform not occuring on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HarleyV/yr8cf8m0/
At issue is the specific section:

```
#circle_menu1:hover, #circle_menu2:hover,#circle_menu3:hover,#circle_menu4:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

For some reason the shadow is drawn, but no variety of transform will work.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as this is my first CSS/HTML project.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
transform:scale(1.5);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
-moz-transform:scale(1.5);
-o-transform:scale(1.5);
-ms-transform:scale(1.5);
```

I believe you should always individually use browser specific properties for stuff like this , with the generic transform also added

Answer (score 1):

Transform does not work well with animations. That basically leaves you with 2 options: Use zoom instead of transform, or apply transform:scale to another element, that does not have any animation properties.
Zoom is not supported by transitions, so if you want to smoothly scale the red elements, I'd recommend the second option.

Luckily, you already have divs with an own id (#first, #second, ...) inside the circle_menu divs, so you can use those: http://jsfiddle.net/stby04/bsr3am0y/

```
#first, #second,#third,#fourth {
    z-index: 4;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    line-height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}


#circle_menu1:hover, #circle_menu2:hover,#circle_menu3:hover,#circle_menu4:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

I think you can clean up my CSS a bit, but it should demonstrate how it could work.

And, as already mentioned, also include the -moz prefix and properties without prefix to make it work in all modern browsers (I actually think that only Safari still needs some -webkit prefixes). And border-radius definitely works without prefix in all current browsers.

Comment: OP had said transfrom was not happening , not so much that it was sloppy and looking for alternatives

Comment: Almost right.. The problem is not that transform doesn't work well with animatiions. The problem is that the animation is setting a transform. An element can not have 2 transforms at the same time, so the transform applied can be the one from the animation (in this case) or the other, but that would ruin the effect.